# Expected output of a addition generator

Tags: algorithm, generator, pseudocode

I'm confused as to the expected output of the following algorithm (this is all the information provided):

> Consider the following small algorithm `X`:
>
> 1. If Algorithm `X` is called with input `n=8`, that is `X(8)`, what will be the output?
> 2. How many iterations occur of the loop for the general value of `n`?
>
> ```
> Algorithm X(n)
> // Input n is an integer
> Start
>     Initialise i to 1
>     While (i ≤ n) do
>         Report i
>         Increment i by 2
>     End while
> End
> ```

I Interpreted this: to be a pre-test loop, where `(i ≤ n)` is checked before iteration and that it is not a generator type algorithm.

With my answers being:

> 1. An output of `1`
> 2. Once for `i ≤ n` (assuming `report i` terminates the function) and zero times otherwise

And the actual answers being:

> 1. `1, 3, 5, 7, 9`
> 2. `floor(n / 2) + 1`

---

I can see my mistake guessing that the function terminates at `report i` (it clearly doesn't), it must be some sort of generator.

But I don't understand how `9` is returned?

This is obviously against the condition `(9 ≤ 8)`. I was told "*this was because this loop is post-test*". But this doesn't seem very intuitive from the `while (cond) do {block}` syntax. And it doesn't seem correct in practice as `(9 ≤ 8)` evaluated before or after the loop still returns `false`.

Should't it be structured as `do {block} while (cond)` (to be considered post-test)? and stop yielding values after `7`?

So:

1. How is `9` returned? i.e, how does the loop continue from the condition `(9 ≤ 8)`
2. Why is `while (cond) do {block}` syntax considered pre-test?

**Edit**:

Wouldn't 2 equal `floor((x + 1)/2) for x >= 0 | 0 otherwise` ?

Comment: Why would it _"terminate at `report i`"_? Are you confusing `report` with `return`? That being said, I think `9` should not be a part of the output

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yeah that's correct. I did mention that I got it wrong, and concluded that it is a generator.

Comment: Yes, `9` should not be an output and `while`/`while do` is doing pretests since the early algorithms. If course this pseudocode language could be defined in another way. Is there a specification for the language?

Comment: @Sebastian No unfortunately not. that was the entire question. Would you say that my answer is also valid? considering the ambiguity?

Comment: Perhaps there are some examples, which use `while` available together with the task? Even in that case, I would deem post-test as wrong (as its definition is common everywhere else). If there is no previous task/course specific information about `while` available, pretest definitely is the only solution (and `9` is wrong). Also the 'actual' answer for 2. is wrong for either pre or posttests as the number of iterations is increased with odd numbers of the input, not with even numbers! So the actual answers have overall 'low quality'. But perhaps floor(1.5)=2 for this task?

Comment: And you are right, even for posttest `9` is a wrong answer. The difference would only be for small inputs `< 1`.

Comment: @Sebastian, see edit that the bottom, do you agree?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the system/definition an integer could always be `≥ 0`. But your answer is doubly correct.